# ssh passwordless in AIX

Tags: aix, sshd

I'm an experienced user of ssh, but now I cannot make it to work with passwordless login in AIX.

I've already revised all settings and permissions many times, but it don't work. I've also checked the configuration `AuthorizedKeysFile` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, and I tried 3 options:

- AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
- AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
- AuthorizedKeysFile ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

What do others configurations should I check in the ssh server ? And how can I get the server log ?

Comment: On the server you are logging into, what is in the user's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file? Should be the public key(s) of users allowed to log in using key exchange. New distros of OpenSSH buy default do not allow DSS/DSA key types. You may need to add those key types using the `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes` option in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And how can I get the server log ?

Open the configuration file and modify the line with `LogLevel` to `LogLevel DEBUG3`. Restart the service (not sure about aix commands). Try to log in using the key (ideally with `-vvv` to verify the key is really offered by the client). Then you should find the logs from `sshd` in log files (depending on where it is directed from `syslog`).

If it will not help you, please, attach the logs to the edited question.

Comment: Stock AIX sshd restart: `stopsrc -s sshd && startsrc -s sshd`

Comment: I cannot find the log file, but I launched sshd manually with the flag -d and so I could get the log on screen. And I got that the problem was permission. I don't know why, but I after the message in log, I noticed that home directory had Xs permissions on. I cleared these bits and it worked.